# What type is a HashMap bucket

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been digging into the `HashMap` implementation in Java. All values are stored in a 'bucket' that is an `Entry` object. I was expecting it to be a collection or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entry is a collection (a light-weight linked list of sorts. Not a java `Collection` strictly speaking). Entries can link each other.

```
    static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    final int hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Nope.  Since it doesn't have to let users access the buckets through the API, `HashMap` gets reduced memory usage and a simpler implementation by just rolling its own very small linked list implementation internally.  It *could* use `LinkedList`, but it has no need of a doubly-linked list, and it's more efficient to pack the link, the key, the value, the key's hash code, etc. into one object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whose implementation you are looking at, but in the [OpenJDK 6 version](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry), it's clear that an `Entry` stores a single value and that each `Entry` forms a node in a linked list.